# Send image in request from python

Tags: python

I am trying to upload an image using POST request. From Postman, it is giving success but when I try same code from python, I am getting an error (payload validation failed). Following is my code in python:

```
import requests
url = "http://10....."

payload = {}
files=[('pdf_file',('passport.jpg', open('/D:/passport.jpg','rb'), 'image/jpeg'))]

headers = {
    'accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization':'<token_here>',
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers = headers, data = payload, files = files)
print(response.text)
```

While invoking request from postman, headers are same as above code. Select form-data in body section and upload image for key "pdf_file".

Is there any difference in both approaches?

Comment: `files` should be a dictionary, no? https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: I tried that too but same error. And this code is same as that in postman. There is no change.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit content type from headers

headers = {
'accept':'application/json',
'Authorization':'<token_here>'
}